# How to hide and display content in a dust template?

Tags: node.js, session, dust.js, kraken.js, dust-helpers

I am a rookie in nodejs. I am making an e-commerce site using kraken framework and dust template. I want to display Log in and Log out text depending upon the session status. My logout and login functionality is working fine. I want to hide the log-in text when the user has logged in and the logout text when the user has logged out.How can I achieve that?
My middleware for checking if a user has logged in is as follows :

```
app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.user = req.user || null;
    next();
  });
```

How can I achieve that using dust-helpers?

Answer (score 1):

At some point, you'll be calling `res.render()` with a template and a context object to render.

First, you need to pass your user object as part of the context:

```
return res.render(myTemplate, {
  ...
  user: res.locals.user,
  ...
});
```

Then, in the template, you can see if user exists:

```
{?user}
  Logout link
{:else}
  Login link
{/user}
```